Merging rows to get all the info in one row
I want to merge rows with info spread over multiple rows into one row.

I want to put the 6 and the 7 in the same row as the 5 with the same numberplate.
This is the end result:


This can be done with a simple formula (maybe a SUMIF?). What happens if there are two columns with entries in a given row? It would be useful to see what the end result should look like

This question is similar to: How to merge rows with Excel?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In Excel there are a number of different ways to accomplish this task.  Here is one.

Select all cells with the data.
Click Insert tab, Table
"Create Table" dialog box opens with selection; click OK.
enter image description here
Select the table; on Design tab, click "Summarize with PivotTable".
In Create PivotTable dialog, Choose Existing Worksheet, and select a cell for the PivotTable starting location.
Click OK.
Select all columns in the PivotTable properties frame.
The excel pivot table will now show the data as you desire, one row for each Item in column 1, and ZR-859-Z with have values in each of the three data columns.

enter image description here

These are the formulas:
F3: =UNIQUE(A1:A7)
G3: =TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF($F3=$A$1:$A$7,IF(ISBLANK(B$1:B$7),"",B$1:B$7),""))
and drag in the range

